# NestJS, Typeorm - where like doesn't return any records

Tags: angular, nestjs, typeorm

I have a problem with typeorm where like. Here is my query:

```
await this.userRepository.createQueryBuilder('user')
                    .select('user.name, user.email, user.creationDate)
                    .where("user.name like :name", {name: '%' + match + '%' })
                  .getMany();
```

When i print `getQueryAndParameters()` I see this:

```
[ 'SELECT `user`.`name`, `user`.`email`, `user`.`creationDate` FROM `user` `user` 
WHERE `user`.`name` like ?', [ '%a%' ] ]
```

Where could it be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
.select('user.name')
.where("user.name ilike :name", { name: '%' + searchTerm + '%' })
```

ilike is case insensitive.